# Firebase libraries with conflicting library versions fail to run my app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i'm using the following firebase library version in my app:

Project's build.gradle:

```
firebase_version = '15.0.0'
```

And the following library dependencies:

App's build.gradle:

```
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$firebase_version"
```

It looks like these versions were released on the 10th of April, however when compiling my app with the updated libraries, it fails to run with the following error:

```
error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found
```

When checking all my library versions, my build.gradle has the following error:

[image]

not sure if anyone has experienced this by any chance since the latest updates? Before updating from 12.0.1, everything was working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override (add to your gradle file) the conflicting library, updating the version to match the ones you already have in your gradle file. Somewhere in your dependencies someone is using an older version of this library and it's crashing with your version:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebase_version"
```

Comment: No go - still having the same problem with compile errors with the same missing file :/

Comment: Show us your app level gradlefile

Comment: Do you still get the "all GM's/firebase libraries..." warning?

Comment: yeah, even when i do the override like above and try to run my project i still end up with the  `error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found` .. I've also compiled the project on  a different computer. Running Android studio version 3.1.1 stable

Comment: Look's like i also had to override the following library: `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase_version" ` . App is now compiling. Thanks!